# Group XML nodes together and display them with two elements in one row

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, modulo

I want to group specific XML nodes together based on a value and display the output with a max of two elements a row.

I have tried a lot but cannot find a working logic.

First of all, here is an example XML:

```
<apples>
    <gala>
        <pattern></pattern>
        <mutated>self</mutated>
        <marketed>Gala</marketed>
    </gala>
    <gala>
        <pattern>stripe</pattern>
        <mutated>Gala</mutated>
        <marketed>Royal Gala</marketed>
    </gala>
    <gala>
        <pattern>stripe</pattern>
        <mutated>Tenroy</mutated>
        <marketed>Obrogala</marketed>
    </gala>
    <gala>
        <pattern>stripe</pattern>
        <mutated>Tenroy</mutated>
        <marketed>Waliser Gala</marketed>
    </gala>
    <gala>
        <pattern>stripe</pattern>
        <mutated>Tenroy</mutated>
        <marketed>Caitlin</marketed>
    </gala>
    <gala>
        <pattern>stripe</pattern>
        <mutated>Imperial</mutated>
        <marketed>Banning Gala</marketed>
    </gala>
    <gala>
        <pattern>stripe</pattern>
        <mutated>Tenroy</mutated>
        <marketed>Smith gala</marketed>
    </gala>         
</apples>
```

I want to group the apples by the mutation but only if they have a pattern. The output should be the following:

```
Mutated from: Gala
Marketed as Royal Gala

Mutated from Tenroy
Marketed as Obrogala :: Marketed as Waliser Gala
Marketed as Caitlin :: Marketed as Smith Gala

Mutated from Imperial
Marketed as Banning Gala
```

Also, an easier solution could be not add "Marketed as Smith Gala" to the group "Tenroy" but instead create a new group "Tenroy" underneath the group "Imperial".

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="apples">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Gala Apples</h2>

            <xsl:for-each select="gala[normalize-space(pattern)][position() mod 2=1]">

                <!-- Add a headline for each mutation -->
                <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::gala[normalize-space(pattern)][1]/mutated != mutated or position() = 1">
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                            <th>
                                Mutated from: <xsl:value-of select="mutated" />
                            </th>
                        </tr>           
                    </table>
                </xsl:if>

                <!-- Build a 2 column Layout for each Gala Apple -->
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%">
                            Marketd as: <xsl:value-of select="marketed" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%">
                            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::gala[normalize-space(pattern)][1]">
                                Marketd as: <xsl:value-of select="marketed" />
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>                           
                    </tr>

                </table>

          </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Problem with my code is, I iterate only through the first node (mod 2=1) while checking for the mutation. This will work fine if every group has an even number of apples in it. If not, it will end up in a mess.

I have also tried to count the numbers of preceding-sibling mutation but it also not working as intended.

A help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I believe you have two separate questions there: The first question is how to group the records by mutation; for this, you should read up on XSLT grouping using the Muenchian method. The second question could be either how to place a `<br/>` after every second occurrence, or how to place every pair (or a single remainder) in its own row. IMHO, the former choice makes more sense, and it is rather trivial to implement using `position() mod 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your processor supports it, you can use the EXSLT set:distinct() function to group the records by mutation, e.g.:

```
<xsl:variable name="groups" select="set:distinct(/apples/gala/mutated)[.!='self']" />
```

instead of using the (more complex) Muenchian method. Then you can use a **key** to get the apples in each group and process them. IMHO, the group should be output as a list, and the two-column display handled by CSS - but if you prefer to handle it by table cells, try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets">

<xsl:variable name="groups" select="set:distinct(/apples/gala/mutated)[.!='self']" />
<xsl:key name="samegGroup" match="gala" use="mutated" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Gala Apples</h2>
<table border="1" >
<xsl:for-each select="$groups">
    <tr><th colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="." /></th></tr>
    <xsl:call-template name="proc">
        <xsl:with-param name="group" select="key('samegGroup', .)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>          
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="proc">
<xsl:param name="group" />
<xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$i > count($group)"/>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:text>Marketed as: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$group[$i]/marketed" />
            </td>
            <td>            
                <xsl:if test="$i &lt; count($group)">
                    <xsl:text>Marketed as: </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$group[$i+1]/marketed" />
                </xsl:if>
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <xsl:call-template name="proc">
            <xsl:with-param name="group" select="$group"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i+2"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```